# Monitor JVM usage for AWS EC2 instance using Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, jvm, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to monitor JVM usage for AWS ec2 instance using Cloudwatch. My java application has been hosted in EC2 instance and please help possible ways to monitor / configure with cloudwatch dashboards as custom metrics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that either through the API (PutMetricData) or through the [CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-first-instance.html) and its [collectd-cloudwatch output plugin](https://github.com/awslabs/collectd-cloudwatch).